# How to get rid of parent webpage styles

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Google Chrome extension.

Extension shows a dialog box (jquery ui, as a div) inside any webpage, in the dialog box user can add some content [HTML content without body, without styles info].

The problem i am facing is, that the styles specified in the webpage are getting applied to the jquery dialog and the content user is adding.

For ex. when i launch my plugin on stackoverflow webpage, all text become center aligned, etc etc.

What is the best way to get rid of parent styles inside a div?

Answer (score 1):

you should look into the reset stylesheets almost every CSS framework comes with. You can take that reset stylesheet and apply all of the reset styles to your specific DIV:

```
div.YourDiv, div.YourDiv * {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:0;
   ...
}
```

which should reset both YourDiv and all elements below. After that, you can get started w/ styling the sub elements as you see fit.

Comment: Wouldn't it also reset all styles on a parent page?

Comment: no, as the style above only resets the specific div YourDiv and all elements that are descendants of this div. Unless there is a div on that page that has the class YourDiv, you should be all set.

Comment: The problem is i do not know what html content user will set inside the div [in this case defining a reset css looks impossible :(]

Comment: Reset doesn't reset User's content, it resets the default stylesheet of the browser. Read here for more info: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 0):

I've done that using an IFRAME, which basically creates a whole new html document inside a box, without the styles from the "parent" page. The other option is to redefine all the styles in your div, but that's very tedious and ugly.